# DatePicker having a background

Tags: android, android-styles, android-datepicker

the problem is that my date picker having an ugly White background behind the date picker

[image: White background]

i just want that background to Disappear

this is My code

```
 public void selectDate(View view) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new SelectDateFragment();
    newFragment.show(Master_.fragmentManager, "DatePicker");
}

public void populateSetDate(int year, int month, int day) {


        Birthdate.setText(year + "-" + month + "-" + day);

}

public class SelectDateFragment extends DialogFragment implements
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int yy = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int mm = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int dd = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    DatePickerDialog dialog =new DatePickerDialog(mActivity,R.style.jehadStyle, this, yy, mm, dd);  
    dialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());  

    return dialog ;
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int yy, int mm, int dd) {
        populateSetDate(yy, mm + 1, dd);
    }
}
```

and this is my style

```
 <style name="jehadStyle" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>

</style>
```

Comment: Try to change parent value with this : @android:style/Theme.Translucent.

Comment: That makes the Date picker black

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

**add this to your DatePickerDialog**

Comment: Works like a charm on old API. At least with API23 -> the Dialog background become totally transparent :s -> don't use it starting API 21

Comment: @Tobliug: what is the solution which can work across all the APIs?

Comment: @MehulJoisar As far as I know, no solution across all API. I use different style regarding the API level

Answer (score 3):

try like this,

```
<style name="jehadStyle" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
        <item name="android:background">@null</item>
    </style>
```

hope it will help you

Comment: `<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>` worked for me

Answer (score 3):

```java
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

use with `DatePickerDialog`

Answer (score -1):

Try with this

```
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

add this line above "return dialog".